# После установки Composer не работает

Tags: php, composer

Я с помощью установочного файла с официального сайта Composer совершил установку. Но после введение команды `composer -V` выводится ошибка

> """" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Перезапустите консоль для начала (полностью закройте и откройте). Ещё лучше перезагрузите компьютер (возможно, path не применился)